# Processing output of python file called inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

this is just the beginning of the fun that I'm going to have with bash scripting
for some reason it always returns `Fail`..
And I don't know why, it has been a looooooooong time that I have done bash scripting but this doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

python /var/lib/scripts/Hudson.py result
if test "$result" = "Success"
then
     echo "Done"
else
     echo "Fail"
fi
```

The python file returns either `Success` or `Fail`

if someone can point me in the right direction for this that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Robert.
PS. The python file converts a `XLSM` file to `CSV` which is already working properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the output of python, you should test it with $() instead

```
#!/bin/bash

if test "$(python /var/lib/scripts/Hudson.py result)" = "Success"
then
     Run next command
else
     Exit the script
fi
```

And it's actually better with [[ ]]

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$(python /var/lib/scripts/Hudson.py result)" == "Success" ]]
then
     Run next command
else
     Exit the script
fi
```

If you mean the exit code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if python /var/lib/scripts/Hudson.py result
then
     Run next command
else
     Exit the script
fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, I can't believe it was something that simple, it always is like that.. :)

Comment: And it's even better if the script uses `sys.exit(value)` where a `value` of 0 indicates success; any other value is a failure. Then you can simply say `if Hudson.py; then ...`